# Make API calls to localhost

Tags: api, python-requests

I have a django project running locally and data can be retrieved from an url endpoint.

I tested it and it works with https://resttesttest.com/ and the chrome extension.

Now I want to retrieve it with a python app.

This is how far I got:

```
import requests 

us = "user"
pw = "password"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/"

r = requests.get(url, auth=(us,pw))
try:
    data_json = r.json() 
    print(data_json)
except:
    data_txt = r.text
    print(data_txt)
```

---

Which returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 403</p>
        <p>Message: Forbidden.</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 403 - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

What am I missing?
Thank you for any help